# Parsing columns into arrays, while discriminating whats in the rows

Tags: c++

I'm trying to parse a text file that is outputted like the example below, my example has limited entries but my actual one has over 15000 lines, so i can't read these in individually:

ID   IC   TIME

15:23:43.867 /g/mydata/dataoutputfile.txt identifier

0003 1233 abcd

0043 eb54 abf3

000f 0bb4 ac24

000a a325 ac75

0023 0043 ac91
15:23:44.000 /g/mydata/dataoutputfile.txt identifier

0003 1233 abcd

0043 eb54 abf3

000f 0bb4 ac24

000a a325 ac75

0023 0043 ac91

Is kind of the output I have. The time column resets every so often.

What I am doing now is making 2 additional columns in addition to the 3 i have in my example. The first column is the conversion of the ID column, into a translation into an understandable message. The second additional column will calculate the difference between each time code, except when the time code resets.

My logic is, is to read each column into an array so I can perform the necessary translations and operations.

I am focusing on getting the timecode differential first, as I think getting the translation will be a bit simpler.

The problem I'm having is getting the entries read into their matrices:

my code looks a bit like this:

```
while(readOK && getline(myfile,line))
{
stringstream ss(line);
string ident,IC,timehex,time,filelocation;
string junk1,junk2;
int ID[count];
int timecode[count2];
int idx=0;

if(line.find("ID") !=string::npos)
{
     readOK=ss>>ident>>IC>>timehex;
     myfile2<<ident<<"\t\t"<<IC<<"\t\t"<<timehex<<"\t\t"<<"ID Decoded"<<"\t\t"<<"DT"<<endl;
     myfile3<<"headers read"<<endl
}

else if(line.find("identifier") != string::npos)
{
     readOK=ss>>time>>filelocation;
     myfile3<<"time and location read";
     myfile2<<time<<"\t\t"<<filelocation<<endl;
}

else //this is for the hex code lines
{
     readOK=ss>>hex>>ID[idx]>>IC>>timecode[idx];

     if (readOK)
     {
          myfile2<<setw(4)<<setfill('0')<<hex<<ID[1000]<<"\t\t"<<IC<<"\t\t"<<timecode[1000]<<endl;
          myfile3<<"success reading info into arrays"<<endl;
     }

     else
     myfile3<<"error reading hex codes"<<endl;
}
idx++;
}
```

Although this code doesn't work correctly. I can't just read in every line quite the same because of the intervening time and file location entries that are inserted to help keep track of when I am looking at in my code.

My gut is telling me that I'm calling the matrix entries too early and they haven't been filled yet, because if I cout number 1000, I get a 0 (i have well over 15000 lines in my input file and I have the boundaries of my arrays set dynamically in another part of my program).

I can't seem to figure out how to get the entries assigned correctly as I am having some inheritance issues with the count variable resetting to 0 every time through the loop.

Comment: I started to edit to put the input file into either a code block (my preference) or a blockquote for added clarity, but I realized that I may be looking at some very long lines that auto-wrapped. Perhaps you should do the edit yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Define `int idx` outside of the scope of the while loop (before the while). As it is now, each time through the loop it will be reset.

Comment: @user1412878, well if its defined inside the loop, then it will be reset to zero each time through. Do you want that? If so, then why do you increment it at the end of the loop. I think the seg-fault is due to something else, maybe an out-of-bounds access now that its incrementing correctly.

Comment: What's the best way to tell where the segmentation fault is coming from through debugging? My tools are pretty limited as I'm editing this file through a text editor, and don't really have access to a true debugging program.

Comment: @user1412878, On Linux you can use gdb, which should be installed if you have compilation tools installed. Im not so familiar with Windows, but I think Visual Studio has something similar. Or you could go "old-school" and put in printf/cout statements in strategic points of the code.

Comment: //edit I found it, I was incrementing idx no matter what type of line was read in. and it should have only incremented when a hex line was read.

Comment: you need the stack trace, also called back trace. Once you see the segfault in gdb, type the command 'bt'. `man gdb` will also help.

Comment: Now I'm trying to get a time difference for the 3rd array(3rd column in my example). A new column named DT will be printed to the text file that has the difference between 2 entries *.010. 

`code`cout<<(timecode[idx+1]-timecode[idx])*.010<<endl;


gives me a bunch of weird negative numbers where it should be correct.

Comment: @user1412878, sounds like a different question.

Comment: Well technically I already mentioned the next step in my original entry, i figured since the program was the same that it wouldn't matter if I talked about it in this entry or not.

Comment: @user1412878, if you create a new question related to calculating time difference and refer to this question, you'll get a better chance of an answer. That way we wont have to continue in these comments. I'll monit the c++ questions for it.